# Flutter/Retrofit: How to call API with multiple sort order in query param using Retrofit in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, retrofit2

I am using Retrofit API calls in my flutter app. So far everything going good until the multiple sorting keys have been added to API so that the final URL looks like as below:

https://example.com/contents?page=0&size=20&sort=startTime,desc&sort=id,desc

My current code with just single sort as shown below:

```
@GET('contents')
Future<HttpResponse<ContentList>> getContents(
 @Query("page") int page,
 @Query("size") int size,
 @Query("sort") String sort,
 @Query("desc") String desc,
);
```

Comment: did you got any solution to this problem??

Answer (score 0):

it would be

```dart
@Query("sort[]") List<String> sorts
```

Answer (score 0):

use **@Queries()**

example

```
@GET('/demo')
  Future<String> queries(@Queries() Map<String, dynamic> queries);
```

Comment: How to ignore null values? Thanks